# How to force MongoMappingContext to be created via MongoDataAutoConfiguration.mongoMappingContext()?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm having an issue with my `@Document` classes not being discovered at start up and it appears to be because the `MongoMappingContext` isn't created via `MongoDataAutoConfiguration` (which  would scan for the `@Document` classes) since it's already been defined elsewhere. By setting breakpoints, it appears that `MongoMappingContext` is instantiated as part of the creation of `MongoTemplate` by the application context.

I'm puzzled because it seems like using repositories in any way would cause this to occur so I don't see how the method would ever be called.

Comment: Add more information about your project structure, `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` and other relevant stuff.

Comment: Auto-Configurations are intended to provide sane defaults if no one else provides a particular bean. `MongoConverter` is created by the auto-config if a bean named `mongoMappingContext` is not defined by your application. Help me to understand why you need eager discovery? `MongoMappingContext` registers types as they are used. Run your app with `-Ddebug=true` then you'll get the autoconfiguration report.

Comment: I'm not creating a `MongoMappingContext` bean; rather, Spring is creating one when it creates the `MongoTemplate` bean. When I run my application I don't find that the types are registered unless they are defined in a Repository interface. In my case, I have an abstract class and I'm defining a repository for that class rather than separate ones for each subclass. If I define 'dummy' Repository interfaces that I don't end up using, then all works as expected. If I leave those out, then Spring tries to instantiate the abstract class which of course fails.

Comment: Hey @roborative, did you found the answer ? I am facing the same issue for "@Document" classes. It says "Couldn't found persistence entity type for type class"...Struggling from last 3 days. Any help could be much Appreciated

Comment: What version of spring-boot do you use?